# iOS: How to keep an App in background that doesn't use Background Audio, Voip, GPS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, background, multitasking

I have an app that nees to stay in background.

It should check some values each 10 minutes so it would not consume battery.

This App would not use any Background Audio/Voip/GPS.
What are the best ways to do this and get Approved by Apple?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you want to get approved by Apple, so I assume it's not for jailbroken devices.

Short answer, you can't. See this question for explanations : [Correct way to poll server in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032829/correct-way-to-poll-server-in-background)

Also it seems there has been some "hacks" to try to have a background app running forever according to this question : [iPhone - Backgrounding to poll for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events)

But anyway, you have quite a big chance to have your App rejected if you try it. If the values you need to check is on a server, you should consider to use push notifications.